# Check if the textarea is hidden or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given is textarea box and I want to check that the textarea is hidden or not. You can use Jquery for that. This textarea does not contain id. I have used style element with which i hide that textarea. textarea is hidden by default when user check on checkbox it can be visible.

```
<textarea <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is it the sole `textarea` child inside a `block` that is easy to find?

Comment: i have used style='display: none; , i just want to check it that the textarea is hidden or visible

Comment: What is the structure surrounding the textarea? You already specified it was `hidden`

Comment: Use this `$("textarea").is(":visible")`

Comment: @Bhupendra Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted to help other people coming to this question

Answer (score 1):

Simple enough

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var element = $('div.myDiv textarea');
    console.log('is hidden: ' + element.is(':hidden')); // check if the textarea inside div that has a class myDiv is hidden
    console.log('is visible: '+ element.is(':visible')); // The opposite is also possible
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
<textarea style="display: none;">
  
  </textarea>
</div>
```

You should look at the [documentation for **is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and at the [documentation for the **:selector** pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("textarea").is(":visible")){
/*code*/
}
```

Comment: Put your id if id is specific

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working

Comment: Could you add a little explanation?

Answer (score 0):

you can get style by using below code

```
var getStyle =  $('textarea').attr('style');`
```

and apply condition according to received style property.

Comment: What if you have multiple textarea? They might all have style. You get yourself an `array`.

Comment: then you can use text area name instead of tag like 
var getStyle =  $(''textarea[name="xyz"]').attr('style');